# Losing data of vector store Chromadb using Langchain

Tags: nlp-question-answering, py-langchain, chromadb

I am writing a question-answering bot using `langchain`. For storing my data in a database, I have chosen `Chromadb`. I have written the code below and it works fine

```
persist_directory = "./db"
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()

vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=documents,
embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
```

When I run this code, I get a list of my documents which I stored.
`vectordb.get()['documents']`

I can see that some files are saved in the `./db` directory.

When I want to restart the program and instead of initializing a new database and store data again, reuse the saved database, I get unexpected results.

I used this code to reuse the database
`vectordb2 = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings)`

But this time when I run the code below it returns an empty list
`vectordb2.get()['documents']`

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `vectordb.persist()` after creating your vector db.

Your code should have been:

```
persist_directory = "./db"
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=documents,
embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
vectordb.persist()
```

Comment: But strangely if I copy paste this location to another project and try to use it there, it doesn't work. Isn't it portable?

Comment: @Joseph Same for me . Created it on a home laptop, then tried to load it in the office - th db seems to be empty...